# Is there an Android equivalent to shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse (from iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, android-videoview, android-video-player

Does Android have a similar method of optimizing videos for network use like iOS? Is there an Android equivalent of [shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriter/1389811-shouldoptimizefornetworkuse)?

Comment: Did you found anything?